# Check for the existence of a Kafka topic programatically in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

How can I know if a topic has been created in a Kafka cluster, programatically, *without* using CLI tools, and before trying to produce into the topic?

I'm running into a problem where the topic doesn't exist, and our application is trying to produce to a non-existent topic, but it's only notified after 90 seconds (metadata timeout).  I'd like to know if there is a way to know, if the topic exists or not, from within Java code, so that we can check that before actually attempting to send the message.  I guess I could look at the code that the Kafka CLI utils uses, but I was wondering if maybe there's an API or an easier way that I may have missed.

Comment: The CLI tool is just a wrapper around the programmatic Java API that you'd end up writing anyway, so why not look at that code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `AdminClient#listTopics()` to check if a given topic exists, as shown below:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
try (AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(props)) {
    ListTopicsOptions options = new ListTopicsOptions();
    options.listInternal(true); // includes internal topics such as __consumer_offsets
    ListTopicsResult topics = client.listTopics(options);
    Set<String> currentTopicList = topics.names().get();
    // do your filter logic here......
}
```

Comment: This API doesn't seem to be efficient if we want to check for existence of a single topic and there can be thousands of them on Kafka.

Comment: If you worry about the potential performance inefficiency, you could use `AdminClient.describeTopics` instead and check existence by capturing UnknownTopicOrPartitionException.

Comment: I don't think so. AdminClient quickly throws `UnknownTopicOrPartitionException` for  non-existed topics after getting the response. You can get known of the existence by trying to capture this exception. As per the performance-wise, do you mean capturing exceptions consumes more JVM instructions?

Comment: Constructing and unwinding exceptions is expensive. Exceptions should be used for exceptional cases, not for normal flow.
See here: https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AdminUtils.topicExists(..)` method for older kafka versions (1.0.0) to check if a topic exists or not :

```
    int sessionTimeOutInMs = 15 * 1000;
    int connectionTimeOutInMs = 10 * 1000;
    String zkHost = "localhost:2181";
    ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient(zkHost, sessionTimeOutInMs, connectionTimeOutInMs, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
    ZkUtils zkUtils = new ZkUtils(zkClient, new ZkConnection(zkHost), false);
    System.out.println(AdminUtils.topicExists(zkUtils, "TopicName"));
```

AdminUtils is deprecated in recent Kafka versions. So you can use `AdminClient` for kafka 1.0 + :

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    AdminClient admin = AdminClient.create(prop);
    boolean topicExists = admin.listTopics().names().get().stream().anyMatch(topicName -> topicName.equalsIgnoreCase("tealium.topic"));
```

Comment: All those APIs are deprecated, so I would not recommend using them. Instead use the `AdminClient`.